# Where in the android code is the phone's name/model number stored, and how is it stored there?

Tags: android, usb, linux-device-driver, android-framework, mtp

What I want to know is how a Android phone, when connected as **MTP**, publishes it's name so that it appears on my computer. I believe that the **mtp/usb** drivers get the value from the upper layers such as the **mtp/usb** java classes in the framework layers. I want to try and change the name that appears on the computer through the Android code itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`/system/build.prop` is the location where phone-specific descriptions and attributes are stored. You can edit that if you have root privileges.
The relevant fields in this file are as follows

[image: Fields]

Comment: I have checked the build.prop.I tried pulling the build.prop and pushing back in a modified one, but the phone's name on my computer stayed the same.

Comment: Are you sure you pushed in the right `build.prop`? Also, did you restart your phone before checking?

Comment: Yeah. I pulled it from the phone and pushed it back. Then i rebooted the phone. The binding of the name, maybe, happens earlier and is not dynamic. Do i need to do anything from the driver level?

Answer (score 0):

Look in [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class. It may be what you want.

Comment: I want to find our how the value gets passed down to the drivers.